# Understanding tree shaking and module breakdown

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to build a library of reusable components|pipes|etc for several small projects that will use them.

Those projects will have some lazy-loaded parts. A typical app consists of several tabs which content are lazy-loaded.

To understand how tree shaking works, I created 3 components :

**compo1.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-compo1',
  template: 'compo1-content',
  styleUrls: ['./compo1.component.scss']
})
export class Compo1Component {
}
```

(same template for `compo2.component.ts` and `compo3.component.ts`)

Those components are embedded in a `SharedModule` as adviced in angular guidelines.

Now, in `Lazy1Module`, `Lazy1Component` only embeds `Compo1Component`:

**lazy1.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lazy1',
  template: '<app-compo1></app-compo1>',
  styleUrls: ['./lazy1.component.scss']
})
export class Compo2Component {
}
```

(and same pattern for `Lazy2Module` and `lazy2.component.ts`). I purposely never use `compo3.component.ts`.

Then, I build the project with `ng build --prod --aot`.

The structure looks like :

```
├── 1.0282cf6b35ff530d4bfa.js
├── 2.701cf269742044ec4b71.js
├── 3rdpartylicenses.txt
├── common.7aac461df5427f420d7f.js
├── index.html
├── main.ef0af895ad2a9362da5f.js
├── polyfills.3f4b55f3bddd0d338786.js
├── runtime.9a8874d6abac70e934ae.js
└── styles.3b0c35b989b1a3ac962a.css
```

I guess that `1.0282cf6b35ff530d4bfa.js` is the 1st lazy module and `2.701cf269742044ec4b71.js` is the 2nd lazy module.

I find that definitions of `compo1` and `compo2` are embedded in `common.7aac461df5427f420d7f.js`

The definition of `compo3` is not included in the build.

Hence, here is what I understand :

1. Components that are never used are excluded from the build.
2. If a component is used in just one lazy-module, it will be embedded in `common.xxx.js` so it will be loaded at startup even if it is only used in a lazy-loaded tab.

When I look at how [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/) is made, it seems that there is 1 module per widget. Does it still make sense to do that (apart from organization purpose)? It seems to me that 1 module per widget or every widgets in one module will produce the same output in term of library loading (in production mode at least).

Should I make 1 module per widget or should I only care about regrouping widget in modules that serve the same purpose?